# Edição de tag wiki tendenciosa

Tags: debate, edição, wikis-de-tags

Estamos vendo uma onda de edições de *tag wikis*. Ótimo!

O problema é que tenho visto várias delas enaltecendo a tecnologia, fazendo marketing ao invés de cumprir o objetivo sobre o que é a tecnologia de forma imparcial e como a *tag* deve ser aplicada no nosso site. O texto deve ser o mais contextualizado possível para o nosso caso e não pode em hipótese alguma ser tendencioso, dizendo que ele é ótimo ou péssimo. Não deve haver qualquer juízo de valor.

Então os analisadores, fiquem atentos para isto e rejeitem edições tendenciosas, ou melhorem tirando a parte tendenciosa quando isto for fácil de fazer.

Tente informar ao usuário sobre isto.

Exemplos de problemas são os qualificadores elogiosos ao produto, técnica, conceito, etc. Em geral acontecem mais com produtos, até porque pegam a descrição da página oficial para por na descrição.

```
o mais rápido
o mais completo
o mais poderoso
o mais fácil
é maravilhoso
resolve todos problemas
é horrível
```

Isto tudo é subjetivo e muitas vezes controversos. Não precisamos dessas informações. E se por acaso for importante dizer isto mesmo, então tem que fundamentar, tem que mostrar que não é opinião, e porque a informação é relevante e que não está fazendo em detrimento de "concorrentes", mesmo indiretamente. Se for relevante mesmo tem que mostrar outro lado. Se algo é obsoleto, é problemático, ok, pode dizer, mas é preciso fazer com cuidado, sem ser muito afirmativo, mostrar que pode haver divergências.

Tem que haver imparcialidade. As regras da Wikipedia cabem bem ali.

As as wikis de tag, até por serem comunitárias não pode representar a posição de uma pessoa. É o local mais rígido do site onde os usuários podem contribuir diretamente. É preciso muito cuidado.

Por mais que seja feito de boa fé, não pode ser aceito elogios ou ofensas aos produtos.

As wikis de tag devem ser usadas para informar como usar a tag e dar informações básicas para quem não sabe sobre o assunto. Estas informações podem e até devem ser bem completas. Pode e é desejável que contenha *link* para a página oficial onde tem todo o marketing.

Comment: Não vou por exemplos pra não causar discórdia, mas tem umas que eu vejo que parecem até que foram tiradas do _press-release_ do desenvolvedor. Acho que é um tópico bom a ser levantado.

Comment: Eu vi algumas delas e optei por pular por causa da história dos chapéus. mas concordo com esse entendimento.

Comment: Tem chapéu incentivando isso? Eu devia ter desconfiado. Um motivo a mais pra negar as edições ruins.

Comment: @bigown fui ver e na verdade não existe nenhum chapéu desses, fiquei com a ideia que havia e por isso foi erro meu.

Comment: @JorgeB. só se for para ganhar a medalha de prata

Comment: Eu sou tão contrário a apontar dedos quanto é possível ser, mas nesse caso acho realmente que a discussão poderia melhorar muito se tivéssemos exemplos de edições que falharam nesse quesito. Assim seria possível tentar chegar num consenso mais claro do teor dos wikis. Acho um debate bastante válido.

Comment: Concordo com @Gabe. Uma clarificação seria útil. Que tipos de comentários são tendenciosos? Por exemplo, dizer que uma linguagem é "muito poderosa"? Ou dizer que é "fácil de aprender"?

Comment: @Molx isto, coisas subjetivas, que não possuem fundamento, não existe consenso, tudo o que não está descrevendo objetivamente o que é aquilo. Na verdade até descrições objetivas nem sempre são necessárias. Isto até não causa problemas, mas descrever o óbvio não ajuda muito. O que as pessoas não entendem é que a wiki de tag é para explicar seu uso aqui e dar informações básicas para quem não sabe nada sobre o assunto. E não queremos é vender o peixe para as pessoas, fazer o serviço de marketing de produtos. Todas descrições ficam melhores sem essas coisas de "o mais rápido","o mais completo"...

Comment: @bigown Concordo. E é esse tipo de exemplo (de onde podia melhorar) que seria importante ter aqui. Senão a conversa fica muito vaga e todo mundo vai sair com uma ideia diferente